# How to write StreamReader type to an image file in python?

Tags: python, python-requests, streamreader, aiohttp

`url=[...]

async with aiohttp.ClientSession(headers=headerschrome) as session:
    task = asyncio.create_task(fetch(session, url))

async def fetch(s, url):
    async with s.request(method='GET',url=url) as r:
        if r.status != 200:
            r.raise_for_status()
        with open('zzz/a.webp','wb') as xd:
            xd.write(r.content)


    xd.write(r.content)
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'StreamReader'`

I receive this error when writing the response content to a file. Trying to convert StreamReader to bytes also fail with

> bytes(r.content)

Also is there a way to append image content to a single file?
Thanks a lot!